# How to prevent copy paste in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In order to to make life hard for content thieves, I'd like to disable copy-paste of rendered texts on vue.js components.

Here is an example template :

```
<template>
  <div id="my-precious-content">
    <div class="container"> 
      <div> Some {{texts}} come here </div>
      <div> Still {{moreTexts}} here </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm wondering how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Moral point of view**: You shouldn't. It's breaking user experience for normal users. They cant copy things to translate them to another language, cant copy links and so on.

**Short answer**: You can't.

**Long answer**:
You can make it a bit harder, but they are still gonna be able to copy it (unless you convert it to an image).
Easiest way to prevent copying is preventing selecting text, you do it with css like that:

```
.container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;  
    -ms-user-select: none;  
    -o-user-select: none;  
    user-select: none;
}
```

---

**Another approach**
You could use [oncopy event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy), but it's not standard and not reccomended for production by mdn web docs, so i'd stick to the css solution.

Comment: Actually this works pretty well, at least as a first line of defense. I just needed to insert the css above to the top level div class. Thanks!

Comment: Most websites that do that, actually cripple the user experience. I don't know how many times I wanted to copy an address just to find out the you cannot select anything. My reaction to crappy websites like that is to close them and never return.

Comment: @str did you even read the question? Do you have some other solution in mind? You're totallt right that it cripples user experience. Advantage of this is, that you can target precisely and disable selecting things only on some elements. Crappy websites you mentioned probably do it for all of the content, right?

Comment: @entio Yes I read the question (why do you think I didn't?) and yes some websites block selection completely. But even if they don't, it still cripples the UX. For example when I visit a website which is not in my mother tongue and want to select a word for translation. Or I want to look something up on Wikipedia.

Comment: @str your comment sound like you criticise the only way there is (i'm pretty sure about that) at least conforming specs. I guess it's a matter of compromise between user friendliness and being harsh on content-thieves. I really think that your comment should be placed under the question itself as it concerns not the solution, but the intention.

Comment: @entio I don't think it is a compromise. It is just hurting normal users and anybody who really wants to copy the content can still do so very easily. No gain, only pain.

Comment: @str anyways, your concern is that it's a bad practice. I do agree. But it has to do with the question itself and not the solution i've offered. You should edit my answer then, why haven't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160266/discussion-between-entio-and-str).